# Flutter Web: Make Button Scroll with Page and then Show in App Bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm developing a Flutter Web application that requires a specific button behavior. Initially, the button should be part of the regular page flow. As the user scrolls down, I want the button to scroll along with the page and then appear in the app bar when it's no longer visible in the regular page flow.[image]

And when scroll:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add code too.

Comment: maybe you can try `Hero` https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations/hero-animations